# Infinite loop useEffect using objects as a parameter [React_Native]

Tags: javascript

```
  const [ state, setState] = useState({
casas: [],
casaSelecionada: '',
 });




  useEffect(()=>{
    dbref.once('value', function(snapshot, prevChildKey){
      setState({
        casas:(Object.entries(snapshot.val())).map( e => e[1].casaItem),
      });
    });
   dbref.off('value'); // according to the firebase website itself,  
                       //this function serves to remove all callbacks 
                      // from one location.
  },[]);
```

I started using the hooks, and I came across an infinite loop problem when trying to set my state, I already looked in several forums and all possible solutions did not solve my problem.
 I happen to be trying to set an array of objects, and when I send update, it says that it does not recognize "state.casas" as an object, but when I pass "state.casas" as the second parameter in useEffect inside "[]", it still in the loop.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: You may not want any dependency for that useEffect. `dbref.on` looks like a subscription to Firebase Realtime Database. If useEffect runs more than once, it will create additional subscriptions each time. You probably want only a single run of useEffect. Also add a return function for useEffect to remove `dbref.off(` to cleanup the subscription upon the component being unmounted.

Comment: when adding the function dbref.off, when executing dbref.on it instead of returning me the data, it simply returns my empty array.

Comment: I'd have to see how you wrote it exactly (are you returning the `dbRef.off`), but basically this is the same thing: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1. That being said, you don't need dependencies for this. Let's take the example of adding an event listener to an HTML element in a web app. You wouldn't want to execute `addEventListener('click', someHandler)` over and over and over to the same element. Also, you'd want to remove the event listener when you weren't needing it anymore to avoid leaks.

Comment: if I use once, there is no need to use "off" as it does the search only once, but either way it returns an undefined array.   
I will edit the code so you can see how I made the call

Comment: I'm not implying you need to use `once`, you can use `on`, it's just important to remember to do `off` at some point also. If you update your code with what you tried, that would definitely help to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an infinite loop because `state.casas` is endlessly being updated. Each time the handler for the firebase `on` triggers which updates `state.casas`, it causes the hook to execute. In addition to that, every time the hook executes, it creates new firebase subscriptions that run in addition to the other existing subscriptions with each updating `casas` constantly causing more executions of the hook. Your `useEffect` should probably only ever be run once as the single firebase subscription is at most what you'd need for that ref to get realtime updates. Also moving the handler to a function will make it easier to cleanup the subscription for when the component unmounts:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  casas: [],
  casaSelecionada: '',
});

useEffect(() => {
  // Move logic to a shared handler for easier `on`/`off`
  function handleValueChange(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
    setState(prevState => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        casas: (Object.entries(snapshot.val())).map( e => e[1].casaItem),
      };    
    });
  }

  dbref.on('value', handleValueChange);

  // Return a function that you can unsubscribe from firebase to avoid leaks
  return () => {
    dbref.off('value', handleValueChange);
  }
}, []);
```

Notice a cleanup function was return at the end of the hook containing the `off`. This is to remove the subscription when the component unmounts. Otherwise you could have leaks. Notice that is a returned function. In your example you are simply calling `off` rather than returning a function which is what the [guide on hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) indicates. If you decide to use `once`, then you probably don't need a cleanup function, but `once` may not be enough if you need constant realtime updates.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: So far so good, but looking at the log I notice that I received it, not just once, but 3 times, the first time my matrix returns the values ​​automatically, the problem is that it updates (even using dbref.of or once ) and return undefined values, in my Log:       
[Thu Apr 16 2020 18:32:48.913]  LOG      ["Casa 1", "Casa 2", "Casa 3", "Casa 1", "Pablo", "Cavaco", "Kauê lindo", "Gabriel"]
[Thu Apr 16 2020 18:32:48.968]  LOG      undefined
[Thu Apr 16 2020 18:32:48.981]  LOG      undefined

Comment: From the firebase documentation on [value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#value): *It is triggered once with the initial data and again every time the data changes.*. It may mean that your dbRef path is incorrect or that you method for extracting `casaItem` in incorrect. Are there values in the database that have undefined `casaItem`? if you log out just the item instead of `casaItem`, what gets returned? Either way, that is now a separate issue dealing with your firebase instance. The above solves the infinite loop issue right?

Comment: I suggested it was this problem because when I updated the page manually with "ctrl S" my items would appear normally. so I thought that the problem was in the rendering part.